# Line detection in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics, feature-detection

My main goal is to detect the little line over the left of the image:

[image]

By detecting line I mean I want a line equation of this form: y = ax + b.

In order to find the line, I tried using [this Hough Transform java class](http://vase.essex.ac.uk/software/HoughTransform/HoughTransform.java.html), which doesn't return the equation I want but at least supposed to find the line, but what happens is that it does not detect the line I want (it actually locates only the horizontal line in the image, and even this is not perfect. The y cord is located perfectly but the x is missed and started from 0, and as you see the line does not start at x=0).

I do not mind detecting all the lines in the image, but at least I have to detect the line I want, the sole line over the left.

I also don't mind using other method than Hough Transform...

P.S already tried [this ImageJ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461910/line-detection-angle-detection-with-java) but it didn't work out for me as well. (I used it as is, maybe it needs to be changed, but I don't really understand what the ParticleAnalyzer does)

Comment: you can detect lines with an edge detection filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) on the image... the rest is pure math... find a line which has the same slope and then move it either x or y until it matches.... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)  (yes, two answers for two questions)

Comment: @MartinFrank I dont see how edge detection can help me here? if you have a complete answer with code could you please post it?

Comment: if you know the edges from the image, you know the the lines drawn on it as well...